# Lenovo T540p, Nvidia GeForce GT 730M, 19.10 Eoan, 4K second monitor problem, 3840x2160 mode not autodetected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I just want my 4K monitor to work as a 4K monitor when it is plugged in. Pixels help, FPS not so much.

Basically what the title says, the screen in my office gets plugged in with an HDMI to Mini Display Port cable. The monitor does show up in the video settings for position and resolution and the other settings. But, 3840x2160 is not an option for the resolution without sending an xrandr command or fiddling with a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

The monitor edid information does have a mode I find acceptable in the factory embedded list of modes. It is using HDMI 1.4 (and not 2.0).

Anyhoo, here is my workaround-- can you see a better way to handle it?

That is my question, is there a better built-in way to do this if the hardware isn't going to automatically configure all the things?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt update

apt -y upgrade

apt -y autoremove

#ubuntu-drivers devices

##  Output:
##  == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
##  modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001290sv000017AAsd0000221Ebc03sc00i00
##  vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
##  model    : GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
##  driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
##  driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
##  driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
##  
##  == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0 ==
##  modalias : pci:v00008086d000008B2sv00008086sd0000C270bc02sc80i00
##  vendor   : Intel Corporation
##  model    : Wireless 7260 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260)
##  manual_install: True
##  driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

apt install -y get-edid

get-edid

##  Output:
##  This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
##  Attempting to use i2c interface
##  No EDID on bus 1
##  No EDID on bus 2
##  No EDID on bus 3
##  No EDID on bus 4
##  No EDID on bus 6
##  No EDID on bus 8
##  No EDID on bus 9
##  3 potential busses found: 0 5 7
##  Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
##  Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
##  Bus 0 doesn't really have an EDID...
##  256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 5
##  ������N�▒�
##ץ�YJ�$PT�������@��t0�pZ��X�Ď!f!P�Q@p6?C!�LP
##        �W55
##           �5tS�_^] &     Pm
##                            < `�`a�rQ� n(UĎ!�▒q X,%Ď!��
##  Њ �->��!▒�
##  Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
##  А @1 
##       @U�!▒5

### <!> As it turns out, I wanted the info on bus 5.
### <!> Let's get the Modelines

get-edid -b5 | parse-edid

##  Output:
##  5
##  This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
##  Attempting to use i2c interface
##  Only trying 5 as per your request.
##  256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 5
##  Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
##  Checksum Correct
##  
##  Section "Monitor"
##          Identifier "W55"
##          ModelName "W55"
##          VendorName "SPT"
##          # Monitor Manufactured week 24 of 2018
##          # EDID version 1.3
##          # Digital Display
##          # Display Physical Size not given. Normal for projectors.
##          Gamma 1.00
##          Option "DPMS" "false"
##          Horizsync 30-80
##          VertRefresh 30-76
##          # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 60Hz
##          #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
##  
##          #Extension block found. Parsing...
##  #WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 95)
##  #WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 94)
##  #WARNING: I may have missed a mode (CEA mode 93)
##          Modeline        "Mode 18" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
##          Modeline        "Mode 0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync 
##          Modeline        "Mode 1" 85.50 1360 1424 1536 1792 768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync 
##          Modeline        "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 3" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 4" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 6" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 7" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 8" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 9" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 10" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 11" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 12" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 13" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 14" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 15" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 16" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 17" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
##          Modeline        "Mode 19" 74.25 1920 2008 2052 2200 540 542 547 562 +hsync +vsync interlace
##          Modeline        "Mode 20" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
##          Modeline        "Mode 21" 27.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync 
##          Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 18"
##  EndSection


### <!> It did not work for me, but you can try generating Modelines with cvt

#cvt 3840 2160
##  Output:
##  # 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
##  Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync

### <!> 60Hz is the default for cvt refresh rate parameter-- my screen is 60Hz...
### <!> A more specifica cvt refresh rate is the optional third parameter


### <!> The only line I see that is 4K is "Mode 0"
### <!> Modeline        "Mode 0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync 
### <!> The quoted part of the Modeline is just a label
### <!> Changing "Mode 0" to "3480x2160" for my own nitpicky self

xrandr --newmode "3840x2160" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync

### <!> cvt generated mode
#xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3840x2160"

### <!> cvt generated mode
#xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3840x2160_60.00"


### <!> To see what's what and the available modes for each
#xrandr -q


### <!> Used arandr for help with xrandr bash command that follows
#apt install arandr && arandr
#  ...save output file as xrandr-example.sh from GUI application
#tail xrandr-example.sh
##  Output:
##  #!/bin/sh
##  xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --off --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA-1-1 --off --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off

### <!> I took that "template" and substituted my own mode and positions

xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1-2 --off --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 pos 960x2160 --rotate normal --output VGA-1-1 --off --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off


### <!> Now I want it to happen when I plug in my monitor
### <!> If W55 is seen, then run my xrandr command

#udevadm monitor

##  Output:
##  monitor will print the received events for:
##  UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
##  KERNEL - the kernel uevent
##  
##  KERNEL[10928.549817] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
##  UDEV  [10928.551102] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
##  KERNEL[10939.083981] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)
##  UDEV  [10939.085367] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1 (drm)


### <!> So, it is a drm UDEV change
### <!> We can use the change to trigger a script

echo "SUBSYSTEM==\"drm\", ACTION==\"change\", RUN+=\"/usr/local/bin/xrandr-for-W55-monitor.sh\"" > /etc/udev/rules.d/xrandr-for-W55-monitor.rules

### <!> Create the script and make it executable

### <!> There's a second way to get edid info

ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid

##  Output:
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-DP-1/edid
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-DP-2/edid
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-eDP-1/edid
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/edid
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-2/edid
##  /sys/class/drm/card1-VGA-1/edid


### <!> To get the bash script "heredoc" to respect indent spacing below, the indents must be tabs...


cat <<-EOF > /usr/local/bin/xrandr-for-W55-monitor.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $(xrandr | grep "HDMI-1-1 connected" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
    then
        #echo $(date) "drm event HDMI-1-1 changed" >> /tmp/checkin.txt
        if [[ $(parse-edid < /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/edid | grep "Identifier \"W55\"" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
            then
                #echo "IT'S W55!!!" >> /tmp/checkin.txt

                xrandr --newmode "3840x2160" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync

                xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 "3840x2160"

                xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1-2 --off --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 960x2160 --rotate normal --output VGA-1-1 --off --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off
            else
                xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --above eDP-1-1
        fi
    else
        xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --off
fi
EOF

chmod 550 /usr/local/bin/xrandr-for-W55-monitor.sh

### <!> That ought to do it...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently all the inputs of my TV work as 4k inputs... but, HDMI2 is supposedly special per the user manual. And HDMI2 works by default where I have to force all the shenanigans above for inputs HDMI1, HDMI3, and HDMI4.

I was able to repeat the exact same failure on a completely different laptop and resolve the exact same problem by simply connecting to HDMI2.

I still think it was neat to get a deeper understanding of xrandr and the video subsystem. (I could have died happy enough without knowing it too though... So, meh.)

Answer (score 1):

As a partial data point, I have connected a Samsung 40" TV (which supports 4k60Hz at 4:4:4 over HDMI 2.0) to a MacBookPro11,3 (mid-2014 15" Macbook Pro) with Nvidia GT 750m at your resolution 3840-by-2160 ("4k") on Ubuntu, using an HDMI to HDMI cable.  I did not have to fiddle with command line beyond getting the correct nvidia driver installed.   I was able to use Ubuntu's Gnome display setting tool as well as nvidia-settings (to play with 4:4:4).  Since I am not currently using it, I cannot consult exact versions although I believe it was Ubuntu 18.04.x with 38x or 4xx nvidia drivers (I vaguely recall suspend problems at higher nvidia versions).  The GT 750m doesn't support HDMI 2.0, only 1.4, and thus 4k60Hz at 4:4:4 is not possible, although 4:2:0 (with poorer rendering of small colored text) may be possible.  On a specific HDMI input of the TV (I had to consult its documentation), I was able to get 4k at 30Hz with 4:4:4, and only 24Hz on the other ports.

Clearly it would be best for auto-detection to work for you.  As to why it's not auto-detecting in your case, I speculate that it's due to the HDMI-to-DisplayPort conversion.  It may be worth testing your laptop with another display that avoids the conversion.